# Salesoforce Archive tasks at anytime by any user

Tags: salesforce

I have a requirement where I need to archive tasks at any time by any user. Salesforce archive duration is one year but I should be able set a task as atchived by me at any time. Or is is there any ...

Comment: Hi @Shebin, there is a new stackexchange site specific to Salesforce at salesforce.stackexchange.com. Come join the community over there! :)